# Android development environment in Docker containersI

Tags: android, docker

I'm currently looking into the way to standardise Android development environments for our products using Docker containers.
I couldn't find such integration yet.

Can anyone point out any existing project which is doing something similar or suggest a the best way to proceed on my own?

Thanks

Comment: are you solve your problem?

Comment: I've written Docker Shell - http://dockershell.io/ for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.docker.user/911) on the docker-user mailing list gives some details about how to access USB devices (including Android hardware) from within a Docker container; but I guess that it is only one little part of the big picture. I hope it can help though.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found [this post](https://plus.google.com/+BradFitzpatrick/posts/CmqtqAShWZJ), it's about building apk packages with a docker instance. This might be a good point to start from.